# Ignite thin Client unstable behavior

Tags: ignite

I am newbie to ignite and trying to play around with the example https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/examples/client/ClientPutGetExample.java

i first tried the example with one server node  and executed the client everything work fine.
then i started a second node with the following config

```
IgniteClient igniteClient = Ignition.startClient(new ClientConfiguration().setAddresses("127.0.0.1:10800","127.0.0.1:10801" )))
with CacheMode.REPLICATED;
```

i re-run the code it work fine, then i kept the same config and i shut down
one of the nodes
then i re-run the code the result is **unstable** sometimes it gives me Ignite cluster is unavailable sometimes it gives me an empty cache

- Thin client put-get example started.
- Created cache [put-get-example].
- Loaded [null] from the cache.

1-as per the documentation ignite thin client is supposed to failover one of the
running nodes.
2- why the cache is note replicated?
is there something that i am missing here
thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like [IGNITE-11599](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-11599) - Thin Client will not failover properly if some of addresses were not up when it started.

It is fixed recently but did not get in any released versions. I'm afraid you will have to work around it by doing manual failovers.

Comment: Thank you for your help